# fullcalendar not rendering the event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, symfony

I am using full calendar with symfony. However the events not been rendered.  I tried every way.

**Controller Code**

```
  /**
 * @Route("/get-booking-to-calendar/{id}", name="booking-to-calendar")
 */
public function BookingCalendarAction($id)
{
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $field = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Field')->find($id);

    $bookings= $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Booking')->findBy(array('field_booking' => $field->getId()));

    foreach($bookings as $booking)
    {
        $booking_array[] = array(
            'id' => $booking->getId(),
            'title' => $booking->getDuration(),
            'start' => $booking->getStartTime(),
            'end' => $booking->getEndTime(),
            'allDay'=>true,
        );

    }
    $response = new Response(json_encode($booking_array));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;


}
```

**Twig**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            timeFormat: 'h:mm',
            allDaySlot:false,

            slotDuration : '00:15:00',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

            events: "{{ path ('booking-to-calendar',  {'id':field_id}) }}",
            // Convert the allDay from string to boolean

            eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                    event.allDay = true;
                } else {
                    event.allDay = true;
                }
            },

        });
    });

</script>
```

**and my json respond is**

```
[{"id":2,"title":4,"start":{"date":"2016-06-18 11:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},"end":{"date":"2016-06-18 12:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"},"allDay":true}]
```

it seems eveything is ok. but the events are not coming on the calendar.

here is html render

[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlaM6.png)

Comment: The above code looks ok. Where is it failing? I don't see the code for that.

Comment: The eventRender function looks to set `event.allDay` to true no matter what. Is that intentional?

Comment: Also, can you post the rendered html of the calendar div?

Comment: Dear Kal, I added the picture.

Comment: I still could not find a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I sort it.

First I create a repository class and add following function.

```
 public function GetBookings($fieldId)
{
    $sql = "SELECT b.id, b.start_time as start, b.end_time as end, CONCAT( c.first_name,', ', c.last_name) AS title FROM bookings b  LEFT JOIN clients c on b.client_id = c.id WHERE b.field_id=:fieldId ";
    $params = array(
        ':fieldId'=>$fieldId
    );

    return $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery($sql, $params)->fetchAll();

}
```

then change my controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/get-booking-to-calendar/{id}", name="booking-to-calendar")
 */
public function BookingCalendarAction($id)
{
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $bookings= $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Booking')->GetBookings($id);
    $response = new Response(json_encode($bookings));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [eventDataTransform](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/) hook? Populate the event object manually and see if you are still getting a problem. Fullcal wasn't parsing my start/end ISO8901 correctly and I was getting the same problem. I had to parse my JSON start/end data into [moment objects](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/) before assigning them to the event object's start/end params in eventDataTransform. Best of luck!

Comment: I tried that way but still not rendering the events